# how to read from a file in linux in c++?

Tags: c++, linux, fstream, filereader, readfile

i have got a problem, I want to write code which reads from file, i tried ifstream type but it doesn't work on my linux. Does anyone had similar problem ? [EDIT] (I write this code in Code Composer Studio,on Code Blocks it works. i have an error that say "method 'fail' could not be resolved.) 
Down below my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
using namespace std; 

int main () 
{ 
ifstream inFile ("input.txt"); 
if (inFile.fail()) 
{ 
cout << "Could Not Open File\n"; 
} 
else 
{ 
cout << "File opened succesfully\n"; 
}  
}
```

Comment: My telepathy machine does not work today

Comment: What do you mean "doesnt work" do you get an error? If so what is it?

Comment: Oh wait i see why! Your code isn't indented properly ...

Comment: @Ben seems your telepathy machine doesn't work either

Comment: please add more details to your description? I can see this code will even not compile because it is malformed.

Comment: @Slava I didnt purchase the package that lets mine work through the internet :(

Comment: If you indent your code properly you may notice a missing `}` at the end of `main()`.

Comment: i didnt mention that i wrote this program in Code Composer studio, on Code bloks it works. i have an error that say "method 'fail' could not be resolved.